# What's the difference between Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY and Float.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java

What's the difference between `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Float.MAX_VALUE`?
Which is greater?
Are they the same?

I came accross them looking for a value that would be greater than every other `float` or failing that all except the greatest. Does either meet that criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, they're not the same thing at all.

`Float.MAX_VALUE` is the largest *finite* value that can be represented in a `float`. You won't find any value greater than that, other than infinity. But you can perform all kinds of other operations on it.

`Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is, well, infinity. Most operations involving an infinity will end up with infinity (either positive or negative).

For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testOperations(Float.MAX_VALUE);
        testOperations(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    }

    public static void testOperations(float input) {
        System.out.println("input: " + input);
        System.out.println("input / 100: " + input / 100);
        System.out.println("input * 100: " + input * 100);
        System.out.println("-input: " + (-input));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input: 3.4028235E38
input / 100: 3.4028236E36
input * 100: Infinity
-input: -3.4028235E38

input: Infinity
input / 100: Infinity
input * 100: Infinity
-input: -Infinity
```

Comment: So, when compared with any other Float, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY will always be greater?

Comment: @Adam: Unless the other float is `NaN`, yes. (`NaN` is neither greater than nor less than nor equal to any float.)

Comment: I wonder why did they implement it that way that `input * 100: Infinity` (for MAX_VALUE test). I guess it would be more logical to throw some kind of exception in that case.

Comment: @Max: This is all specified by IEEE-754, as far as I'm aware. You don't *get* exceptions for floating point arithmetic - even division by zero.

Comment: @Max First of all we're talking about low level hardware here and exceptions there are something completely different than Java's exceptions. But actually IEEE-754 does define several exceptions (so for the right definition of "exception" we actually do get one for division by zero ;) ). And: overflow is also one of them. [See here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html). But Java is most certainly the wrong language for that kind of stuff - you'll even have a hard time doing these things in C.

Comment: no exception but you get trapping to software routines for denormalized and infinities, so potentially huge perf difference between maxvalue and infinity.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question:

> I came accross them looking for a value that would be greater than
>   every other float or failing that all except the greatest. Does either
>   meet that criteria?

Yes, `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is, by its definition, the only `Float` that is greater than `Float.MAX_VALUE`.  It is, however, something of a special case in terms of how it interacts with mathematical operations.

From the javadoc:

[public static final float POSITIVE_INFINITY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) :

> A constant holding the positive infinity of type float. It is equal to
>   the value returned by Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f800000).

[public static final float MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE) :

> A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type float,
>   (2-2-23)·2127. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal
>   0x1.fffffeP+127f and also equal to Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f7fffff).

So, as you can see, according to the very literal definition is that `POSITIVE_INFINITY` is greater than `MAX_VALUE` by one bit.

In terms of their utility, `POSITIVE_INFINITY` provides a value that you can use to recognize otherwise problematic mathematical expressions.  The one used in the JDK source is `1.0f / 0.0f`.  The result of this expression is `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, indicating that you have exceeded the upper bound of reasonable mathematics, never to return.  Given the two constants `POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, you can check to see if a general expression has left the bounds of the useful Floats and whether it was the positive or negative door.

`MAX_VALUE`, on the other hand, represents the maximum value on which you can still apply normal mathematical operations.  For example, `MAX_VALUE - 1.0E32` is a (slightly) smaller number than `MAX_VALUE`.  `POSITIVE_INFINITY - 1.0E32`, however, is still `POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: The example is wrong (and a common mistake). Since `Math.ulp(Float.MAX_VALUE)` is `2.028241E31` (which is much greater than `1.0f`), `Float.MAX_VALUE - 1.0f` is still `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @syme You are totally correct. I was using the mathematical definitions rather than the Java definitions. I’ve changed the example to match actual Java behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more detailed information on IEEE 754 floating point values here: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html